# Jquery: How to only show input value if input is not blank?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a code live preview form with jQuery, so when people type in the input, the related `<span>` will update.

JQuery:

```
var $comment = '';
$(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
        var currClass = $(this).attr('class');
        $comment = $(this).val();
        $('span.'+currClass).html($comment);
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="image-left-url">Image URL: </label>
<input id="image-left-url" class="image-left-url" value="http://"></input>

<code><pre>&lt;img src=&quot;<span class="image-left-url"></span>&quot;/&gt;</pre></code>
```

My question is, for some inputs I have the `value="xx"` part. How can I make it so that if the `input` is blank, `value="xx"` doesn't show up (so that it doesn't show up in the `<span>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $comment = '';
$(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
        var currClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var _val = $(this).val();
        $comment = (_val != 'xx') ? _val : '';
        $('span.'+currClass).html($comment);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UX4a9/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var $comment = '';
$(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
        var currClass = $(this).attr('class');
        $comment = $(this).val();
        if(!$comment){
           $(this).val('xx');
           $('span.'+currClass).hide();
        } 
        else{
           $('span.'+currClass).html($comment).show();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This hides the span if there is ever a comment.

Comment: Thanks @AlienWebguy, but I didnt understood the question well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $comment = '';
$(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
        var currClass = $(this).attr('class');
        $comment = $(this).val();
        var notblank = ($comment != $(this).attr("value"));
        $('span.'+currClass).html(notblank ? $comment : '');
        return false;
    });
});
```